# How to put a rate limit on a celery queue?

Tags: celery

I read this in the [celery documentation for `Task.rate_limit`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.rate_limit):

> Note that this is a *per worker instance* rate limit, and not a global rate limit. To enforce a global rate limit (e.g., for an API with a maximum number of requests per second), you must restrict to a given queue.

How do I put a rate limit on a celery queue?

Comment: Maybe this article will help you implement this yourself https://callhub.io/distributed-rate-limiting-with-redis-and-celery/

Comment: i found the [`celery.app.task.Task` code documentation (v5.0.5)](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.0.5/celery/app/task.py#L183) for rate limiting helpful in understanding its use. **note that this is specific to a _task_** and not a queue, like the OP originally asked about. but as i ended up here after visiting celery's documentation trying to figure out how it worked, figured it may help others.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out it cant be done at queue level for multiple workers.
IT can be done at queue level for 1 worker. Or at queue level for each worker.

So if u say 10 jobs/ minute on 5 workers. Your workers will process upto 50 jobs per minute collectively.

So to have only 10 jobs running at a time you either chose one worker. Or chose 5 workers with a limit of 2/minute.

Update: How to exactly put the limit in settings/configuration:

`task_annotations = {'tasks.<task_name>': {'rate_limit': '10/m'}}`

or change the same for all tasks:

`task_annotations = {'*': {'rate_limit': '10/m'}}`

`10/m` means 10 tasks per minute, `/s` would mean per second. More details here: [Task annotations setting](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-annotations)

Comment: How about some specifics - e.g. how exactly do you tell a worker to do only "2/minute"?

Comment: @spookylukey see my answer below

Comment: After searching for the answer of this question I found that rate-limiting is possible only on task level. Celery does not support queue level rate-limiting.

Comment: so is there a way to get the number of workers dynamically and then a dynamic rate limit?

Comment: Does this still hold in 2019?

Comment: For 2019 I have created an example of how to integrate rate limiting into your tasks when using Celery + Django + Redis (after giving up on Celerys lack of rate limiting features or documentation, which is probably on purpose due to differing app requirements) : https://gist.github.com/Vigrond/2bbea9be6413415e5479998e79a1b11a

Comment: I took @Vigrond's solution and extended it over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66161773/64911

Answer (score 0):

hey I am trying to find a way to do rate limit on queue, and I find out Celery can't do that, however Celery can control the rate per tasks, see this:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#rate-limits

so for a workaround, maybe you can set up one tasks per queue(which makes sense in a lot of situations), and put the limit on task.

Comment: This `rate_limit` is also per worker not per task. If you have two workers consuming that task the rate limit is effectively doubled and so on.

Answer (score -2):

You can set this limit in the flower > worker pane.
there is a specified blank space for entering your limit there.
The format that is suggested to be used is also like the below:

> The rate limits can be specified in seconds, minutes or hours by appending “/s”, >“/m” or “/h” to the value. Tasks will be evenly distributed over the specified >time frame.
>
> Example: “100/m” (hundred tasks a minute). This will enforce a minimum delay of >600ms between starting two tasks on the same worker instance.

Comment: You can set rate-limit on only task level on Flower. Celery does not support queue level rate-limiting.